# Multiple v2 Service Remoting Endpoints in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-remoting

I'm using Service Fabric v6.1.472. We're trying to switch to using Service Fabric Remoting (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting), specifically to use the v2 listeners.

The problem I'm running in to is that the documentation only says how to do it using a single listener via the extension method:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return this.CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners();
}
```

This assumes that

1. The service class implements the remoting interface
2. There is only one remoting v2 endpoint in the host (I need multiple endpoints).

When digging into the decompiled code, it looks like this extension method uses a hard-coded endpoint name, which would make it impossible to use this for multiple remoting endpoints. Further digging revealed that many of the methods used by the extension method are marked internal.

Short of creating my own library, has anyone else found a workaround to this bit of bad design?

**Edit**

Microsoft updated [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#how-to-use-the-remoting-v2-stack). Under the header "Using explicit V2 classes to use the V2 stack," it is clear how to create listeners without the extension method.

Comment: Are you having this issue using .net core or a full net framework? I only have experience having a V1 and V2_1 listener running together in the same service. Why do you want to have multiple V2 endpoints?

Comment: I require multiple endpoints for business reasons, not framework compatibility. The good news is that Microsoft finally updated the documentation (and therefore answered my question). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#how-to-use-the-remoting-v2-stack

Comment: That is good to know. So you managed to have multiple V2 listeners in the same service?